# Get JavaScript access to dropbox without app registration

Tags: java, javascript, api, dropbox

I am going to operate a DropBox account with a Java-application, so I can use their JavaScript codes. But is there a way to get an access to a DropBox account without using an app key and a secret, or maybe some default ones. How can people say that it's impossible when the DropBox web pages do it somehow? It's just confusing for me to examine the long codes of the web pages.

Comment: i think you can access it if the page is in public folder

Comment: http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/how_host_your_website_dropbox

Comment: Had you even read it? I need the scripts to use them in a Java-application, for example for editing files. I am not so dumb not to know how to use the public folder.

Answer (score 0):

from `Dropbox`

> App keys
>
> Dropbox generates a unique key/secret pair for every app, known as the
>   app key and app secret. **These are necessary for authentication** and are
>   unique to just you and just this app. In other words, please don't
>   share these values or reuse them with other apps.

so the answer is no, you can't access an account without a key.

Comment: So how does their website get access to it?

Comment: which website? dropbox? i would guess they have access to anything on dropbox? since its their website. why can't you use the key they provide?

Comment: I am asking the key or scripts used at their website.